# Microsoft Failover Cluster Manager console missing

Tags: failovercluster

Failover cluster feature is already installed in this 2 nodes cluster since many months everything was working fine since yesterday. However, I don't see the Failover Cluster Manager console anywhere, not in MMC, not in the Server Manager's list of Tools, not in System32 folder. The cluster commands through Powershell is working fine. I have checked and confirmed that WMI is working fine and the feature is installed. The server was rebooted yesterday.

Please help to get the console back.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to connect from another server, please check it. What server version do you have?

Comment: ha ha ha.... funny reply, why would I try to connect from non-cluster server? Server is 2012 R2.

Answer (score 0):

With the `Get-WindowsFeature -Name *failover*` PowerShell cmdlet you can check/confirm that management tools are installed on the server. If for some reason they don't seem to be installed you can do it with the `install-windowsfeature` just to include the management tools parameter.

Comment: From the Server Manager, I see the required Roles/Features are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove-WindowsFeature -Name  RSAT-Clustering-Mgmt  
Install-WindowsFeature -Name  RSAT-Clustering-Mgmt
```